# jQuery - Resume animation duration

Tags: jquery, animation

I whant to have an animation pause when `window.active == false` and resume when `window.active == true`.

```
var time = 15;
        if(window.active == true){
            time=time-1;    
            $('#bar').animate({
                width:'100%'
            }, 15000);                  
        } else {
            var myDiv = $("#bar");
            myDiv.clearQueue();
            myDiv.stop();
            time=time;  
        }
```

The problem is that when the animation resumes it restarts the duration and it becomes pregressively slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function stop() reset the animation, and when you restart the animation it's duration is the original again.
To solve that, you can do a timestamp and calculate the remaining durantion when resume.

```
var time = 15, duration=15000, remainingDuration, iniAnimation, pauseAnimation;
if(window.active == true){
     time=time-1; 
     if(pauseAnimation) {  
         remainingDuration -= pauseAnimation-iniAnimation; 
         $('#bar').animate({
         width:'100%'
         }, remainingDuration);
         pauseAnimation = null;
         iniAnimation = new Date().getTime();
     }
     else {
         $('#bar').animate({
         width:'100%'
         }, duration);
         remainingDuration = duration;
         iniAnimation = new Date().getTime();
     }                    
 } else {
      var myDiv = $("#bar");
      myDiv.clearQueue();
      myDiv.stop();
      pauseAnimation = new Date().getTime();
      time=time;  
 }
```